# Getting a SuperNotCalledException pressing back key

Tags: android

I have this class in my android application:

```
public class Academic extends Activity {
String reg, regi, name, course, branch, sem, subjects, present, total,
        batch, success;
GetHttp student;
JSONObject returned;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.academic);
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    reg = app_preferences.getString("Registration", null);
    student = new GetHttp();
    new studentDetails().execute();
}

public void onPause() {
    this.finish();
}

class studentDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
       //get JSON data and display
}
}
```

When I hit back I get this exception:

> android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.erp.centurion/com.erp.centurion.Academic} did not call through to super.onPause()

Please help finding why am I getting this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
public void onPause() {

    **super.onPause()**
    this.finish();
}
```

Only, that is strange to finish the activity in onPause. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as your onPause starts call `super.onPause()`. This may solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onPause` method, you must call `super.onPause()`.

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();
}
```

When overriding some functionality, like Activity pausing, it is required that the super-class implementation is allowed to do its processing. The `SuperNotCalledException` you get have all the hints you need to spot which method is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

change your onPause() method from

```
public void onPause() {
    this.finish();
}
```

to

```
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```